# How to get CSRF Token and pass it into Selenium WebDriver with Java to automate login function for website preventing automation script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a novice in Selenium with Java. I have a tricky case that needs support from an expert. I am trying to automate an e-commerce site with Selenium WebDriver JAVA. As a manual, I login successfully with my registered credential. But when I run my automation script for this login function, the site prevents me from automating this by not generating the CSRF Token for my logging in a request. Every login script running with a validly registered credential, the "Invalid CSRF Token" message is displayed. I know that this site is preventing automation script for spam blocking. But this is my exercise test and I must pass this. So I post this for the support request that whether I bypass the CSRF Token in the login script for automating this smoothly?

Thank you for spending your time and reading my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the CSRF token value and set in request header to resolve this issue.

Please find Robot framework snap of the same issue,

> ${status}    ${cookie_CSRF}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Selenium2Library.Get Cookie Value    X-CSRF
>    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='PASS'    Set Request Header    X-CSRF    ${cookie_CSRF}